# TensorFlow 2, how to reset a stateful RNN hidden state in C++ API?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I am using the C++ API of Tensorflow (v2.3.1) to serve a model (in SavedModel format) that contains a stateful GRU layer. Periodically, I need to reset the hidden states of the model. If I was working in Python and Keras, I could achieve this using `tf.keras.Model.reset_states()`, but alas I need to use the C++ API.

My model is loaded using `tensorflow::LoadSavedModel` function which provides me with a `tensorflow::SavedModelBundle` object. The idea I am pursuing right now is to first access the model graph using `bundle.meta_graph_def.mutable_graph_def()`. I plan to then find the `VarHandleOp` op in the graph corresponding to the hidden state of the GRU and manually fill that tensor with 0s. So far I have not been able to identify the op, and I have not found a way to write values manually to the `VarHandleOp` object. Am I on the right track? Is there another way to reset the states?

Comment: I have also been trying to find a solution to this. Let me know if you find a solution please